# The dot on the folder in PyCharm's side tool

Tags: python, pycharm

What is the meaning of the dot on the folder in this screenshot?[image]

Comment: Couldn't find the screenshot

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2021.3/symbols.html#common-icons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [PyCharm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-tool-window.html#content_pane), the dot means that the folder is a **package**.